# How can create an icon when my app is installed?

Tags: android

Some android applications when installed, add an icon on my desktop. 
How can I do for my apps?

Answer (score 3):

Doing this is not recommended.

Now, there is an option in Google Play Store that when you enable it all installed apps will have a shortcut in the homescreen.

When you do this manually in your app, there may be 2 cases where each of them is disturbing.

1. User choose to add shortcuts automatically in Play Store and you also add one of yours. Thus, there are 2 icons of your app in the homescreen.
2. User choose not to add shortcuts and you add manually so user gets automatically disturbed.

Besides inorder to do this, you have to request a premission from the user. Extra permission is always getting a headache to you.

Comment: And if a ask to  the user to add the icon?